# If $\frac{y}{e^y-1}=\sum_{i\geq 0}B_i\frac{y^i}{i!}$ prove that $B_{2n+1}=0$ for $n\geq 1$

Tags: real-analysis, number-theory

If $$\frac{y}{e^y-1}=\sum_{i\geq 0}B_i\frac{y^i}{i!}$$ prove that $B_{2n+1}=0$ for $n\geq 1$.

The thing is that I would like that $\frac{y}{e^y-1}$ odd, but since it's not the case I can't conclude.

Comment: You would like it to be even, not odd (even though it is neither).

Answer (score 3):

Most simply, the odd part of the function is
$$ \frac{1}{2} \left( \frac{y}{e^y-1}-\frac{-y}{e^{-y}-1} \right) = -\frac{1}{2}y. $$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

You can easily find $B_0$ and $B_1$. Then look at the parity of $$y\longmapsto \frac{y}{e^y-1}-B_0-B_1y$$ and conclude.